# Check the selected class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following function:

```
function next_or_previous(){
    $(document).on('click', 'a.next, a.previous', function (e) {
        var rh = $(this);

         if (rh == 'a.next') { //??
             console.log("next");
         } else if (rh == 'a.previous') {
             console.log("previous");
         }
    });
};
```

I simply want to check what class (`next` or `previous`) was clicked. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can use `hasClass()` or `is()`

```
if (rh.hasClass('next') ){...
```

if you only have 2 selectors you shouldn't really need to check in the `else`

Answer (score 4):

Use `hasClass()` function.

```
function next_or_previous(){
        $(document).on('click', 'a.next, a.previous', function (e) {
           var rh = $(this);
           if (rh.hasClass('next')){ //??
                console.log("next");
           }else if (rh.hasClass('previous')){
                console.log("previous");
          }
      });
   };
```